# Need answer for this series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2^n\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n+1}}(k-1)(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1})$

I stuck on the series. Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (k-1)(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1})=n\sqrt{n}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{k}$$ hence given series has partial sums $$S_n=\frac{1}{2^n\sqrt{2^n}}\left(2^{n+1}\sqrt{2^{n+1}}-\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n+1}}\sqrt{k}\right)=2\sqrt{2}-\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n+1}}\sqrt{k}}{2^n\sqrt{2^n}}=2\sqrt{2}-T_n$$ Wolfram alpha gives the limit to $T_n$ as [$\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto+%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B2%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D%5Csqrt%7Bk%7D%7D%7B2%5En%5Csqrt%7B2%5En%7D%7D)

Comment: would you please give more explanation in your answer on the first line? How could $n\sqrt{n}$ appear?

Comment: Just expand the sum and you'll get the expression